# 2009 Chrysler town and country rpms surge and shifts hard

Tags: transmission

Second and third gear shift hard and it goes to three to four thousand rpms to do so. My fluid is not low please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This isn't really an answer, but IIRC these cars are notorious for transmission problems.  Hopefully someone else has a better fix though.  How many miles are on the car?

Comment: 247,000 miles. It is in really good shape though I think it was a business van.

Comment: Hello anybody???